# osm2pgrouting how to configure mapconfig.xml file

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, xml, osm2pgrouting

I need to customize mapconfig.xml file.

I have to do bike routing so I start with mapconfig_for_bicycles.xml https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting/blob/master/mapconfig_for_bicycles.xml

This configuration ignore, for examples, ways like
https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/409033340
with tag name "bicycle" and tag value "designated" (but also tag name "highway" and tag value "path").

So I edit the xml file adding this rows:

```
....
<tag_name name="bicycle" id="5">
<tag_value name="designated" priority="1.6" id="501" />
</tag_name>

<tag_name name="highway" id="6">
<tag_value name="cycleway" priority="1.0" id="601" />
<tag_value name="path" priority="1.1" id="602" />
<tag_value name="pedestrian" priority="1.1" id="603" />
...
```

With this configuration after import, tag_id is still  602, not 501 as expected.

To have expected result (tag_id = 501) I need to delete the row:

```
<tag_value name="path" priority="1.1" id="602" />
```

But in this way I'm not sure I will import all ways with tag name "bicycle" and tag value "designated" and I cannot have a tag_id for all ways with tag name "highway" and tag value "path".

What is the best way to configure xml file to include the 2 info together?

Answer (score 0):

I undesrtand I have to set the priority parameter.